# Not booting RAM file system embedded in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

We have a Linux embedded system that we would like to boot from Flash file system, but have a RAMFS embedded into the kernel that can be seen by the kernel after boot.

Is it possible to embed a RAM File system inside the Linux Kernel (v3.3), that can be used after kernel boot, that the kernel does not use for booting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Just make a script which mounts a tmpfs on your preferred mount point and that extracts in it a tarball that has been bundled in you rootfs.

Comment: Thanks - and this is one of the options. We were hoping for a "single" copy solution.  i.e. when the kernel is copied (decompressed) from flash and then booted, there would be no extra copy from flash required.

Comment: Well if you are,doing it right you aren't reading that extra tarball from flash on boot.  Then it will be a angle copy solution.

Comment: errr, not sure I follow...the tarball would be in flash file system. Reading flash to decompress kernel (copy #1). Reading the flash file system to untar file (copy #2).